# Jenkins cannot archive artifacts because of wrong directory

Tags: git, jenkins, testing, configuration

My jenkins job does not work and only sends the following error:

> ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "Sources\MyProject\bin\x64\MyProject1*.html". Configuration error?
> Finished: FAILURE

To analyse the problem, I logged onto the machine that runs the Jenkins Jobs and found a directory with the same name as the job. Inside is the pulled git repository, that contains the test project which the job is supposed to use. When I go to the path from the error, I cannot find the supposed directory MyProject1, but another one from another job MyProject2.

So the job clearly uses the wrong path/folder. But when I open the repository through the windows explorer, the correct folder is available.

I checked the jenkins job file for errors like the wrong git branch or configuration, but all paths from the existing project/repo in there are written correctly.

Nevertheless, after deleting the directory for the wrong job on the Jenkins machine, the build regenerates the directory and still tries to use the wrong path with the MyProject2 folder.

Is there a cache file still pointing to the wrong directory, that has to be deleted or something else?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happen that jenkins is not able to find the directory.You need to replace `\` with `\\` when accessing paths in windows. You could use `dir` with the path where your files are present :

```
// dir("<Your path where scripts are present>")
dir ("C:\\Users"){
     <archive step commands>
 }
```

Comment: I checked the paths in the Jenkins file and they seemed correct.

Comment: I also found the solution, which was a messed up Viusal Studio configuration. But thanks for your input and your help.